# How to copy selected data into specific cell (MATCH)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm quite stuck at a problem: I have information in column 3 of a worksheet (I call it sheetin), that needs to be pasted into another sheet in another book.

The copy destination is based of a ROW that matches a value in column A of sheetin and COLUMN that matches a value in column B of sheetin, offset by 1 to the right.

I think my problem lies in the copy destination line. I've previously saved wbin, wbout, sheetin, sheetout as strings. my current code is as follows:

```
iMaxRow = 1200
Dim subj1 As String
Dim subj2 As String
For iRow = 1 To iMaxRow

With Worksheets(sheetin).Cells(iRow, 3)
On Error Resume Next
subj1 = Range("B" & iRow).Text
subj2 = Range("A" & iRow).Text
.Copy Destination:=Workbooks(wbout).Worksheets(sheetout).Range(WorksheetFunction.Match _
(subj1, Rows("2:2"), 0) + 1 & WorksheetFunction.Match(subj2, Columns(, "B:B" & "*"), 0))

End With

Next iRow
```

Any help anyone can offer will be really appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: it's not clear what problems do you have with your code..maybe any errors? However, try to change `Rows("2:2")` to `Workbooks(wbout).Worksheets(sheetout).Rows("2:2")`. The same for `Columns(, "B:B" & "*")`. And also change `Worksheets(sheetout).Range` to `Worksheets(sheetout).Cells`

Comment: Hey simoco, thanks for replying!
I've changed it but i'm still getting runtime error 9: subscript out of range for the copy destination row.

Comment: check `wbout` (this workbook should be opened when macro runs) and `sheetout` - does they really exist? and change `&` to `,`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding correctly, however, if I do, I would just simply use an Index Match Combination of Excel Functions, instead of VBA.

For example:

> =INDEX(B2:B9,MATCH(A2,F2:F9,0))

B2:B9 Being the Array of Which to get value from,
A2 being the lookup value,
and F2:F9 being the lookup array.

Is there a reason why this doesn't work?